# I have 21000 .jpg in single folder. How can I view them?

Tags: software-recommendation, photo-management

I have a setup with Raspberry Pi and `motion` which takes one picture every second and stores then in a single folder. Now there are 21000 of them. I tried to use `eog` for viewing images but it hangs. What's the best software to view them?

Comment: View them all??

Comment: viewing them all in chronological order.

Comment: If you wanna see them all then better make a gif.

Comment: Give `feh` a try. `eog` and GNOME tools in general aren't exactly most efficient. In order to move to next image in folder, that folder has to be indexed, but at least `feh` doesn't create thumbnails gallery unlike `eog`.

Comment: @Zanna OP mentioned the `eog` hangs, and `xdg-open` will open `eog` unless they changed the default program, so that's probably not the best suggestion. Also, the app may be trying to open one at a time, but it does need to index the whole directory to some extend in order to move onto next item.

Comment: I wasn't suggesting `xdg-open` as alternative to `eog` (it's eye-of-mate over here, that's why) but thanks for explaining why it hangs, I figured they were trying to open multiple images or something like that @Serg

Answer (score 1):

You can use a tool to make a movie alias video-clip from the pictures, for example **openshot**. It can be installed from the Ubuntu repositories.

```
sudo apt-get install openshot
```